# Errors when extracting table, what am I doing wrong? Python

Tags: python, ms-word, docx

I'm trying to extract the 8th table in a word document. This is what I have produced so far:

```
import pandas as pd
from docx.api import Document
import os

os.chdir('C:\\Users\\user1\\')

path = 'C:\\Users\\user1\\'
worddocs_list = []
for filename in list(os.listdir(path)):
    wordDoc = Document(path+"\\"+f'{filename}')
    worddocs_list.append(wordDoc)

for wordDoc in worddocs_list:
    table = wordDoc.tables[6]

    data = []

    for i, row in enumerate(table.rows):
        text = (cell.text for cell in row.cells)

        row_data = (text)
        data.append(row_data)

    df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)
```

I am getting an error :

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [8], in <cell line: 13>()
     11     worddocs_list.append(wordDoc)
     13 for wordDoc in worddocs_list:
---> 14     table = wordDoc.tables[6]
     16     data = []
     18     for i, row in enumerate(table.rows):

IndexError: list index out of range
```

There are far more than 8 tables in the document, so I am not sure why it is having this error out of range. I am trying to extract the table from many word documents and put it into excel. Does anyone know how to help?

Many thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  How many elements are there in ```wordDoc.tables``` for all wordDoc?

Comment: Thank you. There are many more than 8 tables in the document. If I run 

import pandas as pd
from docx.api import Document

document = Document('testfile.docx')
table = document.tables[8]

data = []

for i, row in enumerate(table.rows):
    text = (cell.text for cell in row.cells)

    row_data = (text)
    data.append(row_data)
    print (data)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

then I get the right table through which is fine.

Comment: If you are getting index out of range error, then that element is not in list. Trial a run of your code and extract all tables in the doc, to verify what you end up with. What you visually see as a table, may not be recognized as such by the program.

Comment: Ah I see - to trial run and extract all tables, what should I do?

Comment: Could it be that there is an error due to only one of the 500 documents having less than 8 tables?